# Trying to run cutomized hook, used this api "https://type.fit/api/quotes". I'm able to get bunch of quotes in objects, but couldn't get quotes

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-hooks, use-effect

I am a newbie in react and here I am trying to work on customized hooks. I AM using this API "https://type.fit/api/quotes" the problem I'm facing is that, not getting any errors, neither getting any quotes in my outputs. please help me to find and understand what is wrong

```
function App() {
  const [quote, setQuote]=useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchQuote =async()=>{
      await fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes")
        .then(
          (response)=>response.json())
        .then(
          (data)=>{setQuote(data.value)});
          // console.log(text);
      }
    fetchQuote();
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Random Quotes</h1>
      <p>{quote}</p>
      <button>Click For Random Quotes</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is an array

> ```
> // 20211109225522
> // https://type.fit/api/quotes
>
> [
>   {
>     "text": "Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration.",
>     "author": "Thomas Edison"
>   },
>   {
>     "text": "You can observe a lot just by watching.",
>     "author": "Yogi Berra"
>   },
>   {
>     "text": "A house divided against itself cannot stand.",
>     "author": "Abraham Lincoln"
>   },
>   ...
> ```

so `data.value` is undefined, just store `data` in state and render appropriately.

```
function App() {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchQuote = async () => {
      await fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setQuotes(data));
    };
    fetchQuote();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Random Quotes</h1>
      <ul>
        {quotes.map(({ author, text }, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            "{text}" ~{author}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button>Click For Random Quotes</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit trying-to-run-cutomized-hook-used-this-api-https-type-fit-api-quotes-im-a]

[image]

Comment: it is also not working for me

Comment: @SanaMomin Seems to work fine in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trying-to-run-cutomized-hook-used-this-api-https-type-fit-api-quotes-im-a-uopr2). What is the issue you see?